# Does infinite neighborhood of point $p$ necessarily imply $p$ is a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm reading *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, and a question popped into my head when reading the following theorem:

*If p is a limit point of a set E, the every neighborhood of p contains infinitely many points of E.*

I know that this questions has been discussed several times here before, so I'm not gonna repeat it again. However, I'm wondering if the converse (sort of) statement is true? That if a neighborhood of p contains infinitely many points of E, then must p be a limit point of E?

In other words, if a point $p \in E$ is an *isolated point*, must the neighborhood $N_p$ be a finite set?

Tried to find the answer to this question but couldn't find it exactly.

*EDIT:* I realize this is a really stupid question, since if the neighborhood of *p* is large enough, it may contain an infinite amount of points given that $E$ is infinite? So let's put the questions into context.

I'm trying to answer the question regarding if $E \subset X$, where $X$ is a metric room, $E$ only consists of isolated points and $E$ is compact, then can $E$ contain an infinite amount of points?

My idea was to show that the if $\{N_p\}$ is the collection of neighborhoods to *all* points $p \in E$, then its union is an open cover. Then by the definition of compactness, there must exist a finite subcover containing $E$. Thus, there must exist a sequence of points $\{p_1, ..., p_n\} \in E$ such that $E \subset N_{p_1} \cup \ ...\ \cup N_{p_n}$. Finally I'm trying to make an argument that if all points in *p* are isolated, these neighborhood can only contain a finite amount of points, and thus can $E$ not contain an infinite amount of points.

I don't even know if this is the case, and if my reasoning is somewhat reasonable? Sorry for long text guys..

Comment: Remember, the whole space is a neighbourhood of any point $p$ you care to mention!

Comment: A more reasonable question would be: "if *every* neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $E$ then is $p$ a limit point of $E$?" (answer is yes). Just a single neighborhood with this property is not enough. See comment of @user754697.

Comment: Seeing the "general topology" tag at this question, the original claim is not even true. Consider any two-point subset of an indiscrete space.

Comment: To help with your question, a point $x$ being isolated means that $\{x\}$ is open. If you have a space $X$ consisting only of singletons, then $\bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\}$ is an open cover...

Comment: Your $E$ is discrete. And so if it is compact then it has to be finite.

Comment: I sort of understand that intuitively, but how do I prove it? @freakish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That if a neighborhood of p contains infinitely many points of E, then must p be a limit point of E?

Clearly entire space is a neighbourhood of $p$ containing infinitely many points of $E$. So the answer is "no".

> I'm trying to answer the question regarding if $E \subset X$, where $X$ is a metric room, $E$ only consists of isolated points and $E$ is compact, then can $E$ contain an infinite amount of points?

What's an isolated point? It's a point $x\in E$ such that there is an open subset $U\subseteq X$ such that $U\cap E=\{x\}$. So if all points of $E$ are isolated then clearly $E$ is discrete.

And a compact discrete space $E$ has to be finite. Indeed, assume that $E$ is discrete and infinite. Since it is discrete then any convergent sequence is eventually constant. But since it is infinite then there is a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq E$ which is injective (as a function $\mathbb{N}\to E$). This sequence cannot have a convergent subsequence. Contradiction.

Comment: Ah, thanks alot! Do you think a formulation continuing on the track of open covers would work as well? As @user754697 states, $\cup_{x \in X} \{x\}$ is an open cover, without proper subcovers. If E then is compact there must exist a finite subcover, thus the open cover itself must be finite, and the rest follows.

Comment: @smyrback yes, that's a valid reasoning as well.